# Simple batch code to count file contents within a file path?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd, scripting

I am attempting to learn how to create batch file, it's been a tough journey thus far. I am looking for a simple batch file script that can count files within a file path I can provide it with. So far I've only been able to research and find this one:

```
dir /a-d "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\testphotos" | find "*"

pause
```

In my "testphotos" folder, I have 4 sample photo files, but the batch script returns 0 files.

Comment: What's wrong with `dir /a-d "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\testphotos\*.*`?

Comment: I get the following: File Not Found 0

Comment: Not if you have 4 files in the folder, you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an alternative of your script:

```
@echo off
set count=0
cd "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\testphotos"
for %%a in (*.*) do set /a "count+=1"
echo %count%
pause
```

to count only .png files, use:

```
@echo off
set count=0
cd "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\testphotos"
for %%a in (*.png) do set /a "count+=1"
echo %count%
pause
```

Comment: This one actually works, thank you very much. Although one little caveat: It seems that this script will only count files that the .bat resides in, regardless that there is a `cd C:\Users\Me\Desktop\testphotos"` on Line 4.

Comment: I take that back, thank you HackR_360, user error on my end as the filepath was actually incorrect as I was using a pseudo filepath name here on the stackoverflow and there was a typo when I was bringing it over into my machine. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: HackR_360 there was a brief edit you had posted where you were showcasing how to count only ".png" files, could you show it again please?

Answer (score 2):

```
dir/a-d /b "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\testphotos"|find /c /v ""
```

You need to add the `/b` otherwise `dir` will generate header and footer lines.

the `/c` swich to `find` reports the line count that would be output (/c`outputs the count instead).`/v`means "don't match` and `""` empty lines, so the `find` counts `dir` lines that don't match empty lines.